# Android OnClickListener not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a fragment that shows the users details that I pull down from firebase. I am trying to set a **OnClickListener** so the logged in user can change their image but I cant seem to get it to work. I have look at the log Cat and can see no errors. I have look at others doing the similar and cant seem to find out why mine wont work.

**Edit: I found the problem but now have a different problem When the fragment first loads the Onlick doesn't work until i refreshed the fragment then the Onclick works but I don't know why the fragment needs the refreshed for the Onclick to work?**

Fragment;

```
 ImageView adminImage;

  adminImage = v.findViewById(R.id.AdminProfilePicture);
        adminImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Long hold to change image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


       adminImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
               Intent openGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(openGallery,1000);
               return false;
           }
       });
```

Main Activity where the fragment is set;

```
   navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_Account_admin:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new ProfileAdminFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_Games:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new GamesAdminFragment()).commit();

                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_Users:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new AllUsersAdminFragment()).commit();

                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_Fixture:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new FixturesAdminFragment()).commit();

                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_News:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new NewsAdminFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_Contact:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new ContactAdminFragment()).commit();

                        break;
                    default:

                }
                draw.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, draw, toolbar,
                R.string.nav_app_bar_open_drawer_description, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        draw.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_Account);
        }
    }
```

XML;

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grad"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_border">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/AdminProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_margin="9dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

[Img of XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSQr.png)

Full fragment code

```
public class ProfileAdminFragment extends Fragment {
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    TextView uName, uEmail, uPhone;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    TextView userlocation;
    ImageView adminImage;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_admin, container, false);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        userlocation = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //   getLocation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
        }


        uName = v.findViewById(R.id.profileFullName);
        uEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        uPhone = v.findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);

        DocumentReference docR = fStore.collection("Users").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        docR.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    uName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("FullName"));
                    uEmail.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("UserEmail"));
                    uPhone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("PhoneNumber"));
                }
            }
        });
        getLocation();
        // profile image
        adminImage = v.findViewById(R.id.AdminProfilePicture);
        adminImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long hold to change image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        adminImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Intent openGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(openGallery, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        });


        return v;

    }
```

Comment: post whole code, this image whole help

Comment: your long click is it working?

Comment: No, both OnClickListener are not working

Comment: well can you paste your code of the fragment, the portion where you inflate view, and setting the listener

Comment: added full code of fragment there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
So I found out that I was loading my user profile instead of of my admin profile so there was a conflict  when loading the fragment so for the Onclick to work I had to manually refresh the fragment

From this;

```
new ProfileFragment()).commit();
```

To this;

```
new ProfileAdminFragment()).commit();
```

```
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileAdminFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_Account_admin);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add android:clickable="true" in ImageView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rellay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grad"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_border">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/AdminProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="9dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you call the fragment from activity a,
then :
initialize v in the fragment as public static . after that call the setOnClickListener from the activity a.

In your activity :

```
YourFragment.v.findViewById("AdminProfilePicture").setOnClickListener (...);
```

please reply if solved your problem